# How to copy values of all attributes from one instance of an object to another if they are not null or empty

Tags: java

Given a class Person:

```java
String name;
String surname;
String id;
String address;
```

I have an object `obj1` with the following values:

```java
name="Name"
surname=null
id="ABC123"
address="Here"
```

Through an api call I get the following json:

```json
{
   "name":"John",
   "surname":"Doe",
   "id":"A1B2C3"
}
```

which gets mapped into an object `obj2`like this:

```java
name="John"
surname="Doe"
id="A1B2C3"
address=null
```

I want to copy all non-null (or empty string) values of `obj2` into `obj1` so the final result is this:

```java
name="John"
surname="Doe"
id="A1B2C3"
address="Here"
```

I have two problems.
The first one is that I don't want to have to manually type the get/set call for each attribute of the object.
The second problem, is that I want the method to work for any type of object with no or minimal changes.

At the very least, I need the first problem solved. The second one is optional, but would be great to learn a solution too.

Comment: have you tried reflection?

Comment: I don't know how to use it, care to elaborate an answer with that?

Comment: Have you tried using copy constructors? Or a `clone()` or a `deepCopy()` member function? You may also serialize the object and then deserialize it to a new object.

Comment: I stated that I want to avoid having to go attribute by attribute writting setter/getter calls. Doesn't seem like a smart thing to do if you know you are working with complex classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reflection to get all the instance fields and use `Field#set` to copy over non-null values.

```
try {
    for (Field field : Person.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
        if (!Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers())) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            Object val = field.get(obj2);
            if (val != null) {
                field.set(obj1, val);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(obj1);
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    // Handle exception
}
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/2pJ5go)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyClass obj1 = new MyClass(1,"1");
    MyClass obj2 = new MyClass(2,"2");
    System.out.println(obj2);
    copy(obj1, obj2);
    System.out.println(obj2);
}

public static MyClass copy(MyClass obj1, MyClass obj2){
    Arrays.stream(obj1.getClass().getDeclaredFields()).forEach(f -> {
        try {
             f.set(obj2, f.get(obj1));
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    return obj2;
}

static class MyClass {
    int myInt;
    String myString;
    String emptyString = null;

    public MyClass(int myInt, String myString) {
        this.myInt = myInt;
        this.myString = myString;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyClass{" +
                "myInt=" + myInt +
                ", myString='" + myString + '\'' +
                ", emptyString='" + emptyString + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

in case you have private fields you can use

```
f.setAccessible(true);
```

but I don't suggest that.

Answer (score 0):

Reading your question, seems like, you have two classes, in two distinct projects, which, exchange information in json.

So, It is easy if you can use Jackson(default in spring)

You could annotate the target class with the annotation of jackson `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)`